# can sed replace words in pattern substring match in one line?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

original line in file **sed.txt**:

```
outer_string_PATTERN_string(PATTERN_And_PATTERN_PATTERN_i)PATTERN_outer_string(i_PATTERN_inner)_outer_string
```

only need to replace `PATTERN` to `pattern` which in brackets, not lowercase, it could replace to other word.

expect result:

```
outer_string_PATTERN_string(pattern_And_pattern_pattern_i)PATTERN_outer_string(i_pattern_inner)_outer_string
```

I could use `([^)]*)` pattern to find the substring which would be replace some worlds in. But I can't use this pattern to index the substring's position, and it will replace the whole line's `PATTERN` to `pattern`.

```
:/tmp$ sed 's/([^)]*)/---/g' sed.txt 
outer_string_PATTERN_string---PATTERN_outer_string---_outer_string

:/tmp$ sed '/([^)]*)/s/PATTERN/pattern/g' sed.txt 
outer_string_pattern_string(pattern_And_pattern_pattern_i)pattern_outer_string(i_pattern_inner)_outer_string
```

I also tried to use the `regex group` in sed to capture and replace the words, but I can't figure out the command.

Can `sed` implement that? And how to achieve that? THX.

Comment: I don't understand why there are someone voted down this question, so weird. I solved it by myself and in the correctly method. And thanks for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can `sed` implement that?

It can be done using GNU `sed` and basic regular expressions
([BRE](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03)):

```vim
sed '
s/)/)\n/g
:1
s/\(([^)]*\)PATTERN\([^)]*)\n\)/\1pattern\2/
t1
s/\n//g
' < file
```

where

- 1st `s` inserts a newline after each `)`
- 2nd `s` replaces the last (`*` is greedy) `PATTERN` inside `()`s with `pattern`
- `t` loops back if a substitution was made
- 3rd `s` strips all inserted newlines

**EDIT**

2nd `s`ubstitute command edited according to OP's suggestion
since there is no need to match `\n` inside `()`.

Comment: Maybe in basic regular expressions's group, there is not need '\n', should replace to ')', it will more suited for this question case.

Comment: @VictorLee: You're right :) I edited my reply.

Comment: THX, One more thing, could I have the one-line command of your implement code?

Comment: @VictorLee: `sed -e 's/)/)\n/g' -e ':1' -e 's/\(([^)]*\)PATTERN\([^)]*)\n\)/\1pattern\2/' -e 't1' -e 's/\n//g' < file`

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, it is easier to do this in `gnu awk` with `RS` that matches `(...)` substring:

```sh
awk -v RS='\\([^)]+)' '{gsub(/PATTERN/, "pattern", RT); ORS=RT} 1' file

outer_string_PATTERN_string(pattern_i_pattern_pattern_i)PATTERN_outer_string(i_pattern_inner)_outer_string
```

**Steps:**

- `RS='\\([^)]+)'` captures a `(...)` string as record separator
- `gsub` function then replaces `PATTERN` with `pattern` in matched text i.e. `RT`
- `ORS=RT` sets `ORS` as the new modified `RT`
- `1` prints each record to stdout

---

Another alternative solution using lookahead assertion in a `perl` regex:

```sh
perl -pe 's/PATTERN(?=[^()]*\))/pattern/g' file
```

Comment: thx, there are some other methods like awk to solve this question, I just try to use sed.

Comment: You can use sed but sed is not suitable for problems like this. Just see how simple, maintainable and efficient are these 2 solutions as compared to sed

Answer (score 0):

> Can sed implement that?

Yes. But you do not want to do it in `sed`. Use other programming language, like Python, Perl, or `awk`.

> how to achieve that?

Implementing non-greedy regex is not simple in `sed`. Basically, generally, it consists of:

- taking chunk of the input
- process the chunk
- put it in hold space
- shuffle hold with pattern space - extract what been already processed, what's not
- repeat
- shuffle with hold space
- output

Anyway, the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed <<<'outer_string_PATTERN_string(PATTERN_i_PATTERN_PATTERN_i)PATTERN_outer_string(i_PATTERN_inner)_outer_string' '
    :loop;
    /\([^(]*\)\(([^)]*)\)\(.*\)/{
        # Lowercase the second part.
        s//\1\L\2\E\n\3/;
        # Mix with hold space.
        G;
        s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\3\1\n\2/;
        # Put processed stuff into hold spcae
        h; s/\n.*//; x;
        # Process the other stuff again.
        s/.*\n//;
        bloop;
    };
    # Is hold space empty?
    x; /^$/!{
        # Pattern space has trailing stuff - add it.
        G; s/\n//;
        # We will print it.
        h;
        # Clear hold space
        s/.*//
    };x;
'
```

outputs:

```
PATTERN_outer_string(i_pattern_inner)outer_string_PATTERN_string(pattern_i_pattern_pattern_i)_outer_string
```

Comment: THX, I need some time to digest this. Yes, maybe I do not want to do it in `sed` if this is the only one way to achieve that.

Comment: Is this only suit to the example string ? I have update the question, maybe there is something you didn't consider?

Comment: Sure I didn't. And still, the principle will be the same, just a bit more tokenization and hold space shuffeling. Instead of `s//\1\L\2\E\n\3/;` there has to be - first put `\([^(]*\)\)` to hold space, then remember `\(.*\)` also in hold space, replace `PATTERN` to `pattern` on pattern space, restore `\(.*\)` and conitnue.

Comment: emm,,, I think this is hardcoded, and it doesn't general and wasn't fixed the question.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by this:

```
:/tmp$ sed 's/(/\n(/g' sed.txt | sed 's/)/)\n/g' | sed '/([^)]*)/s/PATTERN/pattern/g' | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g'
outer_string_PATTERN_string(pattern_And_pattern_pattern_i)PATTERN_outer_string(i_pattern_inner)_outer_string
```

- make pattern `()` in a new line
- find the `()` lines and replace the `PATTERN` to `pattern`
- merge multiple lines in one line

thanks for [How can I replace a newline (\n) using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed)

Comment: That 4 step process is arguably not as efficient as doing it in a single command